# Ubuntu/Openbox keeps crashing - how to I find the cause

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash

Just recently my laptop (System 76) has been crashing randomly. I have not been able to determine exactly what is causing the crash. It may happen when all I have is one web browser open, or it may hapen with several web browsers and terminals open running resource intense processes. When the crash happens, the screen just goes blank. The fan is still running and the wi-fi light is still on. From there, I hit the power button for ~2sec and it shuts down. Sometimes, I just get logged out.

How can I determine what is causing this crash? I looked all through /var/log, but couldn't find anything (though I'm not sure exactly what to look for...).

NOTE: In trying to post this, my laptop crashed whenever I would hold down the backspace key in this textarea.

UPDATE: This only seems to happen when the power cable is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

When it crashes can you restart X(ctrl+alt+backspace)? If you can do this, this at least narrows it down do an X problem. But my thought is either you have something installed that is causing this. Has it been doing this since you installed Ubuntu, or later on after some change? If so then it must be something that you installed or else your hard disk is just failing. This is what i think.

Comment: ctrl+alt+backspace does not work

Comment: ctrl+alt+backspace is disabled in ubuntu unless you re-enable it.